# TravlePort api : GTID connection

Tags: galileo, travelport-api

In Airticket Universal API part I have following request:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"> 
     <soapenv:Header/> 
        <soapenv:Body> 
     <air:AirTicketingReq AuthorizedBy="Travelport" BulkTicket="false" ReturnInfoOnFail="true" TargetBranch="*******" TraceId="trace" xmlns:air="http://www.travelport.com/schema/air_v33_0" xmlns:com="http://www.travelport.com/schema/common_v33_0"> 
        <com:BillingPointOfSaleInfo OriginApplication="UAPI"/> 
        <air:AirReservationLocatorCode>K82F4Q</air:AirReservationLocatorCode> 
        </air:AirTicketingReq> 
              </soapenv:Body> 
        </soapenv:Envelope>
```

and got following error:

```
<faultstring>Record locator not found.</faultstring>
```

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a permanent error. PNR might become old, or you have a typo in PNR number.

Or you are using PNR number from alternative GDS (uAPI handles Galileo / Wroldspan).